# Python identity vs equality

Tags: python, memory, literals

As far as I know, `is` operator in python returns True only if both objects evaluate the same thing in the memory, and `==` returns True both operands values are equal.

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

So, the code above executes like that.

```py
>>> a = "Text"
>>> b = "Text"
>>> c = "".join(['T', 'e', 'x', 't'])
>>> a is b
True
>>> a is c
False
>>> a == c
True
```

What is going on with this one? I have used `id()` function to check their adresses, and it returned the exact same value for `a` and `b`  but `c` returned something different. Why do `a` and `b` point same thing in memory but `c` points something different?

And as a bonus question: how does python find the value of *string*, *number* literals. I mean; are the addresses of literals `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` or `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ...` the same for different programs? Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if I've used wrong terminology.